# How to write nested select sql query with doctrine query builder?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

My query looks like

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as cnt, ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost
FROM 
    (SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost FROM accounts LEFT JOIN earnings ON earnings.id = accounts.id WHERE earnings.date >= ? GROUP BY earnings.id) src;
```

How to write it using $querybuilder from Doctrine?

I have tried:

```php
        $qb = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('COUNT(*) as cnt, ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost');
        $qb->from(
            $qb->select('SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost')
                ->from('accounts')
                ->leftJoin('accounts', 'earnings', 'earnings', 'earnings.id = accounts.id')
                ->where('earnings.date >= :date')->setParameter(':date', $dto->getFromSqlFormat())
                ->groupBy('earnings.id')
        );
```

But it is not working and I am getting error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a total count of accounts and their sum of total cost from earnings table If so then i guess you can simplify your original query as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) cnt,
       ROUND(SUM(e.cost),2) as cost 
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN e ON e.id = a.id
WHERE e.date >= ?
```

No need for group by if you want a scalar result

In DQL it would be as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) cnt,
       SUM(e.cost) as cost 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\Account a 
LEFT JOIN a.earnings e
WHERE e.date >= ?
```

In query builder it would look like

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('count(distinct a.id) as cnt, sum(e.cost) as cost')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Account','a')
    ->leftJoin('a.earnings', 'e')
    ->where('e.date = :date')
    ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ->getQuery();
```

You can always format your end result from your codebase so I have removed `round` from query builder and DQL

Prior to above make sure you have defined proper relation in your Account entity that points to Earning entity (one to many /many to many) otherwise this won't help

Comment: It won't work, because earnings are divided by date, so we have to sum up cost for each day. 

Could you convert my orginal query?

Comment: @mickris but there is no indication in you original query that earnings are divided by date ?

Comment: I thought it can be deduce from query, at the end you have `group by earnings.id`.
That's why we have to do select from select.

Comment: @mickris Can you update your question and add relevant detail like you expected output along with the mapping defined in your entities that would be very helpful for us

Comment: I do not have mapping.

Comment: @mickris you are using symfony right with doctrine ?

Comment: @mickris then you should following the standards like using ORM you should play around with objects not with database, so first step would be create your entities and define their relation after that you can perform queries on your related objects